# Android поиск в AppBar

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

Я начинающий программист. У меня возникла небольшая проблема. Сделал поиск в AppBar. Он работает как надо, но выглядит некрасиво, когда много свободного пространства. Мне нужно как-то растянуть его по всему AppBar при открытии. Помогите, пожалуйста!

[image: Поиск]

[image: Развернутый поиск]

[Сделано всё вот по этой инструкции](https://phpnick.ru/posts/category/android/51)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так в ресурсах меню:

```
app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
```

либо вот есть тулбар:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tbToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
```

либо вот рабочий вариант:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Вопросы еще по вашей тематике нашел: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133185/how-to-make-searchview-that-covers-the-entire-actionbar-toolbar), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862315/android-full-width-searchview-in-actionbar), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210307/searchview-not-filling-entire-actionbar-by-default-and-not-responding-to-clicki), и [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737464/how-to-make-the-action-bar-searchview-fill-entire-action-bar).

Comment: Благодарю за быстрый ответ. Попробовал оба варианта. Второй не работает, а первый только переносит поле влево при нажатии на поиск, но не растягивает строку.

Comment: Помогла четвёртая ссылка. Премного благодарен.